# Preventing C++ error check from stopping Python

Tags: python, c++, caffe

I'm using [caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) for training convolutional neural networks. Sometimes the training will diverge, which caffe will find using [one of the error checks](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/1479). However, this check will stop both the C++ and Python scripts. How can I catch that C++ has stopped in Python (response in log is: `*** Check failure stack trace: ***` with the previous line refering to the previously mentioned error check) and continue the Python script?

Comment: And what is the information in the failure stack trace?

Comment: Nothing in that line, but the previous line contains: `F0709 19:17:09.947024  5515 solver.cpp:204] Check failed: !isnan(loss) Loss is NaN at iteration: 3`

Comment: This is the check I linked to in my post.

Comment: Do you want to prevent the solver from doing the check? If yes, you can set the solver param ` stop_on_nan`. Or do you want keep the check and just want the C++ portion to terminate more gracefully?